# Multiprocessing pool

Tags: python

Есть такой код (python)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

line = []
for i in range(250):
    line.append(i)


def test(number):
    print('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
    for _ in range(14):
        def test2():
            print(number)
        return test2()


with Pool(5) as p:
    p.map(test, line)
```

Сейчас он выводит, что-то такое

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
1
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
2
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
3
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
4
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
5
 и т.д
```

Можно ли как-то сделать, что-бы он выводил такое:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
и т.д
```

Comment: Кстати, у вас цикл в функции test всегда выполняет только одну итерацию, и сразу завершается.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, делить исходный список на блоки нужного размера, передавать каждый блок в `map`, после обработки каждого блока выводить строку

```
def test(number):    
    for _ in range(14):
        def test2():
            print(number)
        return test2()

block_size = 14

print('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')

with Pool(5) as p:
    for i in range(0, len(line), block_size):
        p.map(test, line[i:i+block_size])
        print('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
```

Вывод:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
9
8
10
11
12
13
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
28
29
30
31
...
```